# GitHub Contributor List

Tags: git, github

Is here anyway to get the list of contributors and the commits info for a gitHub project? I have a GitHub Project list and I want to get the contributor info using Python programmatically.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks for your concern and help.

I tried basic git commands and did not get any info.

Comment: Did you check the GitHub API docs? This isn't a `git` thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Way 1:**

If you want to get the list of all contributors in a GitHub repository then you have to go to the **Insights** tab. Here you get the contributor list and their numbers of commits.

For better understanding, I am including a image of this:
[image]

You can scrap this page using python to get the data. For more, you can read the [Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/viewing-activity-and-data-for-your-repository/viewing-a-projects-contributors)

**Way 2:**

You can use a GitHub action called **[Contribute List](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/contribute-list)**. This will edit your `README.md` file and add the contributor list in it. From this `README.md` file, you can get the data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can GET [https://api.github.com/repos/{organization}/{repository}/contributors](https://api.github.com/repos/%7Borganization%7D/%7Brepository%7D/contributors)

For example, to see the Istio contributors that you would see on the web page https://github.com/istio/istio/graphs/contributors you can do

`curl "https://api.github.com/repos/istio/istio/contributors"`

For example, to see the first 100 contributors and their commit count do

```
import requests, json

logins = json.loads(requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/istio/istio/contributors?per_page=100").text)
for login in logins:
    print(f"{login['login']} has {login['contributions']} commits")
```